# How to check if a file is in given directory

Tags: c, file, directory, cygwin, subdirectory

I tried to search that in many words, but for some reason I am solely given references to questions like "How to check if file or directory exists".
Instead, I would like to check if a given file is located in a given directory.

The problem is that the file, the directory or both can and sometimes have to be passed as a relative path, instead of absolute path.

Is there any windows/unix function that checks on that?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the distinction. Checking to see if a file exists, using the file path, is how you determine if a file is located in that directory. If it doesn't "exist", then it's not located there. Are you asking something different?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield What if the file is presented as an absolute path? It needs to detect that and tokenize it to path and file or compare it up to the last `\\` with the path provided IF it is absolute path.

Comment: One way to implement this if you use some function to resolve a relative path to an absolute path, make sure both are resolved and then use `strncpy`, but I am wondering if there is a standard function to do that.

Comment: The absolute path *is* the file path. Almost every API that I'm aware of that determines if a file exists or not uses the absolute path, because that is the actual designation of the file. Why would (and how could it) only use the file name?

Comment: There’s no need to tokenize it. All the checking functions want a path, which bay be absolute or relative, and may not include any slashes (or backslashes) if it is relative.  Do you need to distinguish between regular files and directories, symlinks, sockets, FIFOs, character and block special devices?  Or does the name simply need to exist?  Does it matter whether you could open the file?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield If it uses only the filename, this can be detected and assumed that it is a file relative to the program path and so the other argument, the directory should be absolute path to that directory or maybe empty string or `.\\` to return matched.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is sufficient that only the name exist. The function can require that one is a file and not a directory.

Comment: So you're asking what API's there are that resolve paths to absolute paths, then.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield This can help to implement the function I am looking for, yes. I am not afraid to write code, I just prefer to use standard and tested functions whenever possible. If there is no function to do all that for me, I will write it myself and post it here, so that people can use it. That is If someone don't do that before me of course.

Comment: Well, there's [realpath](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) for Linux/Unix, there's [PathCanonicalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizea) from the Windows Shell API, among others.

Comment: `relpath` works OK, sadly it won't work for Windows. WIndows's `PathCanonicalizeA` however doesn't work, if used the same way. It would simply return the same string or remove some unneeded characters.

Comment: Well, there are lots more out there. They are all over Google.

Comment: `GetFullPathNameA` I will make the function now.

Comment: in linux, use the `stat()` function.  Give it the path/filename and it will fill in a struct with the details of the file, if it exists at that path, else it will return an error indication

Comment: @user3629249 make a cross-platform variant of my function, post it as an answer that I accept maybe?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of using the `stat()` function regardless if the 'filename' is a full path or just the file name

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>



#if 0
           struct stat {
               dev_t     st_dev;         /* ID of device containing file */
               ino_t     st_ino;         /* Inode number */
               mode_t    st_mode;        /* File type and mode */
               nlink_t   st_nlink;       /* Number of hard links */
               uid_t     st_uid;         /* User ID of owner */
               gid_t     st_gid;         /* Group ID of owner */
               dev_t     st_rdev;        /* Device ID (if special file) */
               off_t     st_size;        /* Total size, in bytes */
               blksize_t st_blksize;     /* Block size for filesystem I/O */
               blkcnt_t  st_blocks;      /* Number of 512B blocks allocated */

               /* Since Linux 2.6, the kernel supports nanosecond
                  precision for the following timestamp fields.
                  For the details before Linux 2.6, see NOTES. */

               struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access */
               struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification */
               struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change */

           #define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec      /* Backward compatibility */
           #define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
           #define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
           };
#endif

bool doesFileExistInDir( char *path, char *filename )
{
    struct stat myStat;
    int statStatus;

    char pathname[ strlen(path) + strlen( filename ) + 1];

    if( !strchr( filename, '/' ) )
    { 
        pathname[0] = '\0';
        strcat( pathname, path );
        // strcat( pathname, "/" );
        strcat( pathname, filename );
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy( pathname, filename );
    }

    if( (statStatus = stat( pathname, &myStat )) != 0 )
    {
        // then file not accessible -or- directory not readable -or- file does not exist
        perror( "stat failed" );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Won't work, if @filename is an absolute path :) But +1 for an example of using `stat`. I use `stat` often to get integralities of a file.

Comment: It is the core problem. Checking whether file exists in directory is easy, but it gets more tricky if the file is presented as an absolute path. If you read the question body and not just the question title you will see that it is asked precisely with an inclination to scenarios like that.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used to determine if `dirname` is the directory of `filename`.

```
int file_is_in_directory (char *filename, char *dirname) /* [!] Windows-specific */
{
    char   filename_full[MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
    char   dirname_full[MAX_PATH]  = {'\0'};
    char*  file                    = NULL;

    GetFullPathNameA(filename,  MAX_PATH,   filename_full,  NULL); /* [!] Check rval */
    GetFullPathNameA(dirname,   MAX_PATH,   dirname_full,   NULL); /* [!] Check rval */

    if(!strncmp(dirname_full, filename_full, strlen(dirname_full)))
    {
        return 1; /* File is located in directory */
    }

    return 0; /* File not contained */
}
```